# Intended font won't appear in Javascript mode (Processing)

Tags: fonts, processing

So the following code is intended to output the word "HI" in the specified font. However, in Javascript mode, the font is the default font and not Old Standard.
Can someone please explain this to me?

```
PFont myFont = createFont("OldStandard-Regular.ttf",30);
textFont(myFont);
text("HI",50,50);
```

Answer (score 2):

p5.js doesn't support `createFont()` (at least not yet).
You should see this in error console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: createFont is not defined
```

You can use [loadFont()](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadFont) though, just make sure you preload the font first:

```
var myFont;
function preload() {
  myFont = loadFont('assets/OldStandard-Regular.ttf');
}

function setup() {
  fill('#ED225D');
  textFont(myFont);
  textSize(36);
  textFont(myFont);
  text("HI",50,50);
}
```

Alternatively use a callback function when the font is loaded:

```
function setup() {
  loadFont('assets/OldStandard-Regular.ttf', drawText);
}

function drawText(font) {
  fill('#ED225D');
  textFont(font, 36);
  text('HI', 50, 50);
}
```